# Mapping array to class properties

Tags: c#

I am wondering what is the best way to map array values to properties in a class. Consider the following sample array describing information for an airport:

```
        [0] "6523"  string
        [1] "00A"   string
        [2] "heliport"  string
        [3] "Total Rf Heliport" string
        [4] "40.07080078125"    string
        [5] "-74.9336013793945" string
        [6] "11"    string
        [7] "NA"    string
        [8] "US"    string
        [9] "US-PA" string
        [10]    "Bensalem"  string
        [11]    "no"    string
        [12]    "00A"   string
        [13]    ""  string
        [14]    "00A"   string
        [15]    ""  string
        [16]    ""  string
        [17]    ""  string
```

I have the following class:

```
    public class Airport
    {
        public Airport(string[] data)
        {
            Action<string>[] PropertyMappings =
            {
                x=>this.Id=x,
                x=>this.Ident=x,
                x=>this.Type=x,
                x=>this.Name=x,
                x=>this.Latitude=x,
                x=>this.Longtitude=x,
                x=>this.Elevation=x,
                x=>this.Continent=x,
                x=>this.CountryIso=x,
                x=>this.RegionIso=x,
                x=>this.Municipality=x,
                x=>this.ScheduledService=x,
                x=>this.GPSCode=x,
                x=>this.DataCode=x,
                x=>this.LocalCode=x,
                x=>this.HomeLink=x,
                x=>this.WikipediaLink=x,
                x=>this.Keywords=x
            };
            for(int i=0;i<data.Count();i++)
            {
                PropertyMappings[i](data[i]);
            }
        }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Ident { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Latitude { get; set; }
        public string Longtitude { get; set; }
        public string Elevation { get; set; }
        public string Continent { get; set; }
        public string CountryIso { get; set; }
        public string RegionIso { get; set; }
        public string Municipality { get; set; }
        public string ScheduledService { get; set; }
        public string GPSCode { get; set; }
        public string DataCode { get; set; }
        public string LocalCode { get; set; }
        public string HomeLink { get; set; }
        public string WikipediaLink { get; set; }
        public string Keywords { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
Airport airport = new Airport(data);
```

Do you think this is a good way to do the mapping from the elements of the array to the properties of the class or is there a better way. I couldn't really find anything online.
Obviously I haven't done all of the safety checks etc. This is just a small experiment.

Comment: Will the array always have 1 element for each property? That is to say, you don't need to support arrays with only a few of the properties.

Comment: Yes always exactly one value for each property

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically this looks good but it can be improved.

- Also, you won't find any hints about casing variable names which are local to a method in the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) you should consider to use `camelCase` casing.
- the mapping of the properties should be extracted to a separate method and be called from the constructor. In this way you can reuse it and inside of the constructor the amount of code is reduced.
- let your conditions and variables breathe. This `for(int i=0;i<data.Count();i++)` would look much nicer like `for (int i = 0; i < data.Count(); i++)`
- instead of `i<data.Count()` you should use the `Length` property of the array. But to be on the safe side, you should use something like

  ```
  int minLength = Math.Min(data.Length, PropertyMappings.Length);  
  for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++)
  ```
- some would say you should use `var i=0;` instead `int i=0;`
- Because the `Airport`'s  properties won't be changed, the setters should be `protected`.

Comment: The C# goldie is within sight ;-)

Answer (score 8):

As you said that you will always have the right number of elements in the array, I would suggest the following:

```
public class Airport
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Ident { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longtitude { get; set; }
    public string Elevation { get; set; }
    public string Continent { get; set; }
    public string CountryIso { get; set; }
    public string RegionIso { get; set; }
    public string Municipality { get; set; }
    public string ScheduledService { get; set; }
    public string GPSCode { get; set; }
    public string DataCode { get; set; }
    public string LocalCode { get; set; }
    public string HomeLink { get; set; }
    public string WikipediaLink { get; set; }
    public string Keywords { get; set; }

    public static Airport CreateFromData(string[] data)
    {
        if (data.Length != 18) {
            throw new ArgumentException("...");
        }
        return new Airport
                   {
                       Id = data[0],
                       Ident = data[1],
                       Type = data[2],
                       Name = data[3],
                       Latitude = data[4],
                       Longtitude = data[5],
                       Elevation = data[6],
                       Continent = data[7],
                       CountryIso = data[8],
                       RegionIso = data[9],
                       Municipality = data[10],
                       ScheduledService = data[11],
                       GPSCode = data[12],
                       DataCode = data[13],
                       LocalCode = data[14],
                       HomeLink = data[15],
                       WikipediaLink = data[16],
                       Keywords = data[17]
                   };
    }        
}
```

Depending on usage I would suggest that you alter the accessibility of the setters on the properties and consider making the default constructor protected (if you only want to create via a data array).

## Why am I making this suggestion?

1. Keeps it simple
2. It's about 30 times faster than your method
3. You can view the code as a schema for the data array. I.e. `Type` is the third element

## Edit

As RufusL notes in the comments, it would be a good idea to add a null check for the data array:

```
public static Airport CreateFromData(string[] data)
{
    if (data == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
    }
    if (data.Length != 18)
    {
        ...
```

Further to my comment about my proposed solution being faster - it's not because your code is slow in any way. If you want a dictionary of mappings of property -> index in data array your code will be slower **but that probably wont matter**.

You could just move your array of property mappings to a field. Just change the signature to `Action<Airport,string>[]` you'd then populate it like:

```
Action<Airport, string>[] PropertyMappings = 
{
     (a, s) => a.Id = s,
     // ...
}

public static Airport CreateFromData(string[] data)
{
    // Guards omitted.
    var result = new Airport();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) 
    {
        PropertyMappings(result, data[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

(all of the code in the edit has just been typed directly in the browser, if it doesn't compile, hopefully it should be close enough to correct.)

Comment: I like this. I'm not sure how OP's code would react to an array with only 10 elements, but I know *exactly* how this would react to it.

Comment: I can see your point. I wanted to be able to select what index each property corresponds to and store that data in some kind of data structure. Now that I look at what I've done yesterday, it seems way too complicated for something as simple as that. Still do you have any idea how I can achieve that? I want to have something like a Dictionary<string(or whatever else),int> and store the name of the property or some reference to it as the key and the index of the data for that property in the value.

Comment: Also could you please explain why my initial solution is so slow?

Comment: Your initial solution isn't slow per se, it's just that adding a layer of indirection through your `Action`s is a lot slower than trivially newing up the object with direct array access. As to your other question, reflection and an attribute would be one option. I don't have time right now but I'll update either tonight or tomorrow with an example of what I'm thinking. The speed **shouldn't* matter in real world workloads - it was about 750,000 creations per second.

Comment: Would recommend adding a conditional check for `data == null` before you try to access the `.Length` property. Either a separate `if`, or added to your existing one: `if (data == null || data.Length != 18)`